# using boolean array for indexing in numpy for 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I use boolean indexing to select elements from a numpy array as

```
x = y[t<tmax]
```

where t a numpy array with as many elements as y. My question is how can I do the same with 2D numpy arrays? I tried

```
x = y[t<tmax][t<tmax]
```

This does not seem to work however since it seems to select first the rows and then complains that the second selection has the wrong dimension.

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 50 but corresponding boolean dimension is 200
```

#

Here is an example

```
x1D = np.array([1,2,3], np.int32)
x2D = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], np.int32)
print(x1D[x1D<3]) --> [1 2]
print(x2D[x1D<3][x1D<3]) --> error
```

The second print statement produces an error similar to the error shown above. I use

```
print(x2D[x1D<3])
```

I get

```
[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]
```

but I want

```
[[1 2]
 [1 2]]
```

Comment: `y[t<tmax]` works fine with 2D arrays too. Can you show with a sample what exactly isn't working?

Comment: What is `t` here? A 2D array as well?

Comment: Python processes each indexing operation `[]` independently.   `temp[t<tmax]` followed by `x=temp[t<tmax]`.  So each step has to make sense by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [28]: x1D = np.array([1,2,3], np.int32) 
    ...: x2D = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], np.int32)
```

The 1d mask:

```
In [29]: x1D<3                                                                                               
Out[29]: array([ True,  True, False])
```

applied to the 1d array (same size):

```
In [30]: x1D[_]                                                                                              
Out[30]: array([1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

applied to the 2d it selects 2 rows:

```
In [31]: x2D[_29]                                                                                            
Out[31]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

It can be used again to select columns - but note the `:` place holder for the row index:

```
In [32]: _[:, _29]                                                                                           
Out[32]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

If we generate an indexing array from that mask, we can do the indexing with one step:

```
In [37]: idx = np.nonzero(x1D<3)                                                                             
In [38]: idx                                                                                                 
Out[38]: (array([0, 1]),)
In [39]: x2D[idx[0][:,None], idx[0]]                                                                         
Out[39]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

An alternate way of writing this '2d' indexing:

```
In [41]: x2D[ [[0],[1]], [[0,1]] ]                                                                           
Out[41]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

`ix_` is a convenient tool for tweaking the indexing dimensions:

```
In [42]: x2D[np.ix_(idx[0], idx[0])]                                                                         
Out[42]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

Or passing the boolean mask to `ix_`:

```
In [44]: np.ix_(_29, _29)                                                                                    
Out[44]: 
(array([[0],
        [1]]), array([[0, 1]]))
In [45]: x2D[np.ix_(_29, _29)]                                                                               
Out[45]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

Writing `In[32]` so it's close to to your try:

```
In [46]: x2D[x1D<3][:, x1D<3]                                                                                
Out[46]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int32)
```